# VBA JSON imported but not parsing correctly

Tags: json, vba, parsing

I've imported the VBA JSON library into my VBA project but I can't get it to create the JSON object properly. I've fallen at the first hurdle.

Even the example code that they give isn't working:

```
Sub test()


Dim Json As Object
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson("{""a"":123,""b"":[1,2,3,4],""c"":{""d"":456}}")

' Json("a") -> 123
' Json("b")(2) -> 2
' Json("c")("d") -> 456
MsgBox Json("c")("e") = 789

End Sub
```

This gives the following answers:

a

2

456

null

I've selected the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library and added the VBA Dictionary class.

Comment: If you don't need to support Mac you can remove the dictionary class

Comment: `MsgBox Json("c")("e") = 789` here you're passing the result of adding a new key and value to Json("c") to Msgbox: that operation doesn't return a value, so there's nothing to show.  I can't explain that first "a" though

Comment: Looking at the locals window, it's created a dictionary of the first tier of nodes but nothing below that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the expected results.

```
Sub TestJson()

    Dim Json As Object
    Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson("{""a"":123,""b"":[1,2,3,4],""c"":{""d"":456}}")

    Debug.Print Json("a")        '--> 123
    Debug.Print Json("b")(2)     '--> 2
    Debug.Print Json("c")("d")   '--> 456
    Json("c")("e") = 789         'create new key and value under "c"
    Debug.Print Json("c")("e")   '--> 789

End Sub
```

*Be very careful using the Watch window when dealing with Dictionary objects*: just having an active watch on a dictionary key can cause that key to get added.

Comment: IDNKT - I did not know that re: Watch Window and keys.... why on earth would it do that?

Comment: You're exactly right. I got so stressed about the watch window not showing the object properly, it didn't even occur to me that it could be working. Thanks very much!